# camel control not reaching doFinally in case of exception

Tags: apache-camel

In below camel route there is try and finally block in spring DSL, the control doesn't reaches finally block in case there is 404 Http status code returned.Why is this happening as the expectation is that the finally block should get executed irrespective of any expection or errors in try block.The response returned is :org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking localhost:8080/testUri

```
        <camel:doTry> 
          <from uri="http://localhost:8080/testTry"/>
          <!-- Non existence service called below returns 404 Exception--> 
          <to uri="http://localhost:8080/testUri" /> 
       <camel:doFinally>    
          <to uri="log:inFinally" />
       </camel:doFinally>
   </camel:doTry>
```

Update i tried to throw an exception in the try block and even this exception was thrown and returned in response and call in finally block not executed at all.

Comment: Could be a problem with Camel as I suspect the authors expected an exception to be specified. If you add in a doCatch, does the doFinally branch then get called?

Comment: Yes if i put in a doCatch the call does goes to doFinaaly then.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to handle the exception somewhere in your application. If the exception is thrown all the way to the camel context and isn't handled there, the routing of that exchange stops and the doFinally never occurs.

Comment: I don't want to catch and handle exception , i want the finally block to be executed irrespective of any exception or non exception , shouldn't this try finally block work similar to Java ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is where Java's try/finally differs from Camel's. Try putting a generic catch all global <onException> for java.lang.Exception with <handled><constant>true</constant></handled> and a log statement and see if it goes to the <doFinally> after the exception is "handled".

Comment: if i put in doCatch to catch java.lang.throwable then the doFinally is executed but i guess then the whole purpose of having doFinally seems to be getting lost then or is this a camel defect then?

Comment: I think that the expectation is that an exception is handled **somewhere** in your camel context before executing a finally. This varies from Java where the finally executes regardless. I am unsure the intentions of the camel development team--it couldn't hurt to open up a JIRA and let them either explain themselves or fix it.